# Memory leak in [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] even though with ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios5, memory-leaks, nsmutablearray

I am working heavily on Memory Fineturning and most of the problems are solved with the help of stackoverflow. But finally I got struck with a serious memory leak with NSMutableArray initialization.

```
- (NSMutableArray *)children {

    if (!_children) {

        _children = [NSMutableArray new]; // <-- here is the memory leak
    }

    return _children;
}
```

- I am working with a project where we are using 100% ARC.
- Perticular class initialization is not triggered none other than the main thread (no threading has been used).
- but... this is the only place where we are using recurtion
- moreover the statments

  @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *children;

  @synthesize children = _children;

are there in the respective .h and .m files...

Waht can be the problem....?

Thanks in advance for you effort...

more info...

```
- (id)init {

    if (self = [super init]) {

        [self setIsRoot:NO];
//        [self setChildren:[NSMutableArray new]]; // <-- was before, but I moved to custom setter
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initAsRoot
{
    if (self = [self init]) {
        self.level = -1;
        self.index = -1;
        self.isExpaned = YES;
        self.value = @"Root";
        self.isRoot = YES;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: "Particular class initialization is triggered in main thread" this is the problem. You are accessing this getter within several threads concurrently, aren't you?

Comment: Thanks for your interest, but I am not using any threads... its clearly defined above newly (please see again)... may your suspicion is right because it has been called by recursive method. Again... no threadings involved.

Comment: I see. Then try to put into allocation code (after the "nil"-check) NSLog() statement with some text, and you'll see that your array is allocated multiple times.

By the way, if you can, show some kind of recursion you are using OR print out some contents of the class where this setter is defined. Is this is a custom setter of a property or something? Please clarify since there is a missing part of the code in your question

Comment: I can see now that it is custom synthesized getter of a property. Try declaring it like @property (nonatomic, strong, getter = children) NSMutableArray *children;

Eventually this won't help, it's just a style preference - to declare that you are overriding getter/setter of the property. And [NSMutableArray array] creates autoreleased object (and ARC modifies this to "[[NSMutableArray array] retain]") and is stored in local autoreleased pool. You should use [NSMutableArray new] or alloc] init] pair instead (still just a style preference)

Comment: I will post you an answer. Please add the code from your comment into the question

Comment: hmm... it was in the custom init method... I have moved it to custom setter method just to pinpoint the problem exactly... Furthermore I have tried like [NSMutableArray new] and no difference.

Comment: I've figured out before posting an answer - that doesn't make sense at all. If you are setting array with +1 ref. count to a property in the -init method, then it should never enter the body of the "nil"-check in that getter. Please post expanded version of your code as much as you can, still not a clear picture.

@Goppinath about [NSMutableArray new] - as I already pointed it is a style preference, it won't solve your problem but might help a little with memory overhead